# Codeigniter in subfolder doesn't work with AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, nginx

I'm trying to set up this [Clock application](https://github.com/colinjlacy/clocks) from github.
All changes i did are, changing the database configuration so Codeigniter application is connected to database. My web page opens perfectly, but it looks like it has some problems accessing Codeigniter resources.
[image]

Maybe is the problem in Nginx server directive, so here is my Nginx code

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/clocks.si/public_html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name clocks.si;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }

        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
        }

}
```

This is my Nginx access log, where we can see it has problem loading resources (404) from Codeigniter

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/angular/angular.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/angular/angular-route.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/controllers/clockCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/controllers/addCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/controllers/projectCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:12 +0100] "GET /app/services/dbSrvc.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:13 +0100] "GET /server/index.php/projects/load HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2016:14:31:13 +0100] "GET /app/views/welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://clocks.si/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
```

**UPDATE**
I also tried to set up this application on windows machine using WAMP and it working without any other needed configuration except configuring database information, so i'm assuming it must be something on nginx side
**...**

I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you set the base URL in https://github.com/colinjlacy/clocks/blob/master/server/application/config/config.php ?

Comment: Yes i already tried several combinations of base_url. nothing did the job done
- http://clocks.si/server/index.php/
- http://clocks.si/index.php/
- http://clocks.si/server/
- http://clocks.si/

Comment: it was nginx fault. i finally successfully reconfigure it and it's working, thx for help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfiguration of nginx server directive did the job for me.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/clocks.si/public_html;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name clocks.si;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /server/ {
                index /server/index.php;
                try_files $uri /server/index.php/$uri;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }


        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
        }

}
```